# How to sum distinct values in RTF (BI Publisher)

Tags: reporting, rtf, obiee, bi-publisher

Transaction ID |Amount| Date

1              |200   | 20/04/2020

1              |200   | 21/04/2020

2              |300   | 22/04/2020

3              |400   | 23/04/2020

1              |200   | 21/04/2020

4              |200   | 17/04/2020

2              |300   | 22/04/2020

How to I sum the amount where transaction ID is unique? Need this for both a subtotal and a grand total on a RTF file BI Publisher. Tried this but failed  but returns empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that uses the for-each-group function, and a running total variable.

```
<?for-each:record_set?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'running_amount',0)?>
<?for-each-group:record;transaction_id?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'running_amount', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'running_amount')+amount)?>
<?end for each group?>
<?end for each?>
Non-Unique Sum:<?sum(record/amount)?>
Unique Sum<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'running_amount')?>
<?end for each?>
```

Sample Data

```
<record_set>
<record>
<transaction_id>1</transaction_id>
<amount>200</amount>
</record>
<record>
<transaction_id>1</transaction_id>
<amount>200</amount>
</record>
<record>
<transaction_id>2</transaction_id>
<amount>300</amount>
</record>
<record>
<transaction_id>3</transaction_id>
<amount>400</amount>
</record>
<record>
<transaction_id>1</transaction_id>
<amount>200</amount>
</record>
<record>
<transaction_id>4</transaction_id>
<amount>200</amount>
</record>
<record>
<transaction_id>2</transaction_id>
<amount>300</amount>
</record>
</record_set>
```